# static allocation of array of structures in c

Tags: c, gcc

I believed that declaring the array ***record*** of the structure ***student***, having an  array of another structure (***StudentData***) as a member, would allocate automatically static memory for all members. However this program crash [Segmentation fault (core dumped) in the line record[2].percentage = 81.5;]

In other words I believed that for **record[0]** I would have allocated statically sizeof(int), sizeof(float) and an array of 30 of 220 bytes each one (20 for **name** and 200 for **address**). Even the debugger confirms this hypothesis, however the program crash.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong or if I have miss understood static allocation of array of structures in c or something else.

I am using gcc.

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <string.h>;

typedef struct StData{
    char name[20];
    char address[200];
} StData;

struct student{
    int id;
    struct StData StudentData[30];
    float percentage;
};

void tgin_ini(struct StData tgin[],int tgin_size){
int n;

    for(n=0;n<tgin_size;++n){
        tgin[n].name[0] = '\0';
        tgin[n].address[0] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(){
    int i,n;
    struct student record[2];

    for(n=0;n<2;++n){
        record[n].id=1;
        record[n].percentage = 86.5;
        tgin_ini(record[n].StudentData,30);
    }


    // 1st student's record
    record[0].id=1;
    strcpy(record[0].StudentData[0].name, "Raju");
    strcpy(record[0].StudentData[0].address, "Planet earth, island called america");
    record[0].percentage = 86.5;

    // 2nd student's record         
    record[1].id=2;
    strcpy(record[1].StudentData[1].name, "Surendren");
    strcpy(record[1].StudentData[1].address, "Planet earth, island called europa");
    record[1].percentage = 90.5;

    // 3rd student's record
    record[2].id=3;
    strcpy(record[2].StudentData[2].name, "Thiyagu");
    strcpy(record[2].StudentData[2].address, "Planet earth, island called asia");
    record[2].percentage = 81.5;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("     Records of STUDENT : %d \n", i+1);
        printf(" Id is: %d \n", record[i].id);
        printf(" Name is: %s \n", record[i].StudentData[i].name);
        printf(" Name is: %s \n", record[i].StudentData[i].address);
        printf(" Percentage is: %f\n\n",record[i].percentage);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`record[2]` accesses the third element of `record`, which only has two elements, as it is declared `struct student record[2];`. Either change this to `struct student record[3];` so that you have the needed space, or change your code to only have two students.

Comment: OMG I lost four hours in this. Thank you a lot @R_Kapp